# How do I do an 8 bit stack?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I already have a 4 bit stack, but I don't know how to make it an 8 bit one. It's part of a much bigger project, I'm making a "soda machine simulator" on a fpga (basys 2, ISE Webpack). This is how it looks like so far:

The module implementing the stack:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity stack is

  port

  (
  A: in std_Logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  S_aux: in std_Logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  Q_aux: in std_Logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  clk_2:    in  std_Logic;
  clr_2:    in  std_Logic);

  );

end entity stack;


architecture logic of stack is

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  component unidade_74LS194 is

  port(
        d:  in  std_Logic_Vector ( 3 DOWNTO 0 );
        q:  out std_Logic_Vector ( 3 DOWNTO 0 );
        s:  in  std_Logic_Vector ( 1 DOWNTO 0 );
        L:  in  std_Logic;
        R:  in  std_Logic;
        clk:    in  std_Logic;
        clr:    in  std_Logic);

  end component;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Q_3, vector_d_3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
Q_2, vector_d_2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
Q_1, vector_d_1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
Q_0, vector_d_0: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);


begin

vector_d_3(3) <= A(3);
vector_d_3(2) <= Q_3(2);
vector_d_3(1) <= Q_3(1);
vector_d_3(0) <= Q_3(0);

R3: unidade_74LS194 port map(vector_d_3, Q_3, S_aux, Q_1(3), A(3), clk_2, clr_2);

Q_aux(3) <= Q_3(3);


vector_d_2(3) <= A(2);
vector_d_2(2) <= Q_2(2);
vector_d_2(1) <= Q_2(1);
vector_d_2(0) <= Q_2(0);

R2: unidade_74LS194 port map(vector_d_2, Q_2, S_aux, Q_2(3), A(2), clk_2, clr_2);

Q_aux(2) <= Q_2(3);


vector_d_1(3) <= A(1);
vector_d_1(2) <= Q_1(2);
vector_d_1(1) <= Q_1(1);
vector_d_1(0) <= Q_1(0);

R1: unidade_74LS194 port map(vector_d_1, Q_1, S_aux, Q_1(3), A(1), clk_2, clr_2);

Q_aux(1) <= Q_1(3);

vector_d_0(3) <= A(0);
vector_d_0(2) <= Q_0(2);
vector_d_0(1) <= Q_0(1);
vector_d_0(0) <= Q_0(0);

R1: unidade_74LS194 port map(vector_d_0, Q_0, S_aux, Q_0(3), A(0), clk_2, clr_2);

Q_aux(0) <= Q_0(3);



end logic;
```

The 74LS194 part:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity unidade_74LS194 is
    port(
          d:    in  std_Logic_Vector ( 3 DOWNTO 0 );
          q:    out std_Logic_Vector ( 3 DOWNTO 0 );
          s:    in  std_Logic_Vector ( 1 DOWNTO 0 );
          L:    in  std_Logic;
          R:    in  std_Logic;
          clk:  in  std_Logic;
          clr:  in  std_Logic);
end entity unidade_74LS194;

architecture logic of unidade_74LS194 is

  SIGNAL flw: std_Logic_Vector ( 3 DOWNTO 0 );

  procedure logic_pattern (
    signal ff0: in std_Logic;
    signal ff1: in std_Logic;
    signal ff2: in std_Logic;
    signal b: in std_Logic;
    signal s: in std_Logic_Vector ( 1 DOWNTO 0 );
    signal o: out std_Logic
        ) is
  begin
    o <= (
        ( b and (not s(0)) and (not s(1)) ) OR
        ( ff0 and (not s(0)) and s(1) ) OR
        ( ff1 and s(0) and (not s(1)) ) OR
        ( ff2 and s(0) and s(1) )
    );

  end procedure;

begin

  main: PROCESS ( d, s, R, L, clr, clk, flw )
  begin

    flw <= "0000";

     If ( clr = '0' ) then
       flw <= "0000";

     elsif ( clk = '0' and clk'event ) then

       logic_pattern ( R, flw(1), flw(0), d(0), s, flw(0) );
       logic_pattern ( flw(0), flw(2), flw(1), d(1), s, flw(1) );
       logic_pattern ( flw(1), flw(3), flw(2), d(2), s, flw(2) );
       logic_pattern ( flw(2), L, flw(3), d(3), s, flw(3) );
  end if;

  end process; -- main
  q <= flw;

end architecture logic;
```

The part that is really annoying me is the 74LS194 logic. It's the part that is responsable for the push/pop operation.

Comment: Have you looked up the data sheet of the 74LS194? Anyway this looks like a school assignment as the code is far from what anybody would design to build a stack. A real stack module would have a 'pop' and 'push' port and the core can be written in, I guess, about four lines of code.

Comment: Neither the entity declaration for stack nor the architecture body for unidade_74LS194 are valid VHDL and don't illustrate your problem, which seems unclear. "The part that is really annoying me is the 74LS194 logic" isn't a specific problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VHDL (more of a verilog guy), but a stack is basically just a memory, an address that increments and decrements, and input and output buses for writing / reading data.

When you say you have a 'four bit one' I think you mean that the memory entries are 4 bits wide, so to make an 'eight bit one', just increase the memory width from 4 to 8, and change the input and outputs.